# mariadb crash and even online database users lost permission

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I really need help with a mariadb crash. Earlier today mariadb stopped working. i tried various things to get back with mariadb until i moved ib_logfile0 ib_buffer_pool to another location and so i was able to start mariadb but all database users seem to have lost permission.
I thought at the time that ibdata1 might be corrupted.
I changed mysql root password because I didn't have mariadb root access but all database users lost access to the database.
i tried to make a backup of all databases "mysqldump -u root -p -A > mydb.sql" but i get the error
"Table 'crmidentiq.tblactivity_log' doesn't exist in engine" when using LOCK TABLES

I'm out of ideas on how to solve this problem and repair users' permission.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Check and fix tables mysql.global_priv (for new mariadb versions) or mysql.users (for old versions) , these 2 tables contain your credentials

Comment: your information was very useful. thanks but i cant login to mysql, with root i see
"Can't connect to local server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)"

I checked the permissions and group are mysql.mysql , permission 777 in mysqld.sock. in /etc/mysql/my.cnf file
I have
[client-server]
socket = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
I tried to create another mysqld2.sock but I still can't login with the same error
"Can't connect to local server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)"

Comment: Sorry to hear , maybe check the permissions of the specific file  (111) might be refereing to that try going to the location and giving execute premissions to it specifically